Proof that $\mathbb{R}$ is not a finitely generated vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$

Prove that $\mathbb{R}$ is not a finitely generated vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$.

That's my attempt.
Assume for the sake of contradiction that $\mathbb{R}$ is a finitely generated vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ and we call this vector space $V$.
Then there exists a finite set $S$ with $span(S)=\mathbb{R}$.
By the reduction theorem there exists a basis $B$ with $B\subset S$ and $B$ is finite since $S$ is.
We know that $\mathbb{R}$ itself is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ and we call this space $W$.
Therefore $V$ is a subspace of $W$ and we know by the dimension theorem that $dim(V)\leq dim(W)$. We know that $dim(W)=1$.
It's clear that $dim(V)>0$. Therefore we have that $dim(V)=1$ and $B=\{v\}$ with $v\in\mathbb{R}$.
Case 1:If $v$ is rational choose $\sqrt2\in\mathbb{R}$. Because $B$ is a basis there exists a $\lambda\in\mathbb{Q}$ with $\sqrt2=\lambda \cdot v \in \mathbb{Q}$ which is a contradiction.
Case 2:If $v$ is irrational choose $2\in\mathbb{R}$. Because $B$ is a basis we have that there exists a $\lambda\in\mathbb{Q}$ with $2=\lambda\cdot v\in\mathbb{R-Q}$ which is a contradiction too.
This completes the proof.
My question  is if my strategy using subspaces and dimension works.

If R were finitely generated over Q then R would be countable, but it is not.

@MikhailKatz I know but I can't use this because we haven't proven this in my linear algebra class.

Unfortunately for you, whenever you have a field extension $K\subseteq F$ and some $F$-vector space $X$, $\dim_F(X)$ and $\dim_K(X)$ (i.e. the dimensions of $X$ as an $F$- and $K$-vector space respectively) satisfy the relation $\dim_F (X)\dim_K (F)=\dim_K (X)$, so in your case $\dim(V)\le \dim(W)$ will turn out to be false, if you start digging.

@Arthr, When you use the notion of dimension you need to specify over which field exactly you are computing the dimension.

@SassatelliGiulio I didn't know this because I'm at the moment just a beginner. We haven't covered field extensions yet. Could I fix my strategy or is this approach doomed?

You can notice that $\operatorname{span}_{\mathbb Q} (\sqrt p, , p , \text{prime} )$ is infinite dimensional and a sub vector space of R

@julio_es_sui_glace Thank you! I think this might be too advanced for my class.

Not really, if you know the definition of dimension already it is very elementary, it only requires a small background in arithmetics (but not high level) do you wish me to write you a proof?

Has your teacher perhaps told you that $e$ is transcendental (or that $\pi$ is)?  Then it would follow that the smallest field intermediate field (between Q and R) containing $e$ must have infinite degree over Q and therefore R does also.

@MikhailKatz I think this is too much for OP, they do not know that $\mathbb R$ is irrational so transcendentality is overkill.

I don't think that countable and uncountable is too advanced for your classs. This is often teached even before linear algebra. See for example this post, or this one.

@julio_es_sui_glace it's not that I don't know that $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable. We  have proven that in real analysis. But my professor wants us to use only results of his lectures. It would be very nice if you could show me that proof.

@DietrichBurde We have covered this only in real analysis and my professor wants us to use only results of his lecture.

@Arthr Did your professor also introduce the natural numbers? Because if not, you are not allowed to use them. Countable is a similar basic notion. Alright, that $\Bbb R$ is not countable requires an argument. But it should be common knowledge for all lectures.

@DietrichBurde We did this in fact. I wasn't sure about what I'm allowed to use because I'm fairly new to this.

In the linked duplicate post, the proof by markvs seems to be what you are looking for.
